# Unmetered VS Metered Bandwidth

Tags: bandwidth

What is the difference between unmetered and metered bandwidth? There are some web hosting companies that offer unmetered bandwidth. Does that mean it's unlimited bandwidth?

Answer (score 3):

Metered bandwidth will cost based on how much bandwidth you use.

Unmetered bandwidth doesn't keep track of bandwidth usage and won't cost any additional.

This is *not* the same as limited or unlimited, you may only be entitled to a maximum amount of bandwidth still, but you'll end up paying more for metered should you get closer to your limit.

[This link](http://blog.iweb.com/en/2012/11/unmetered-hosting-traffic-bandwidth-guide/11615.html) has more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Unmetered hosting plans also disclose the exact amount of bandwidth, RAM, and storage which is offered. No guessing, no confusion, and no surprises to worry.

In case of metered bandwidth you pay as per your bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 0):

The above link that says “this link” just takes you to a site and is not for the specific purpose of answering any such questions.

Comment: Above where say what huh? What are you talking about!?

Comment: You might want to share a link to another answer using the "share" link of that answer.